# SQL query to re-align corrupt data (ie. field form line 3 goes to same field in line 4 for 225 lines)

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to a dodge Excel upload, we corrupted some data between rows 6800 and 7024. For these rows, the `description` value for each row needs move down to the next row.

I was thinking of something like:

```
UPDATE `llx_entrepot` 
SET `description`= (
    SELECT `description` 
    FROM `llx_entrepot` 
    WHERE `rowid` = `rowid` -1) 
WHERE `rowid` >= 6800 AND `rowid` < 7025
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I fix this code to make the needed adjustment?

Comment: How could `rowid = rowid - 1` ever be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-join so you can pair each row up with the following row.

```
UPDATE llx_entropot AS t1
JOIN llx_entropot AS t2 ON t1.rowid = t2.rowid - 1
SET t1.description = t2.description
WHERE t1.rowid BETWEEN 6800 AND 7025
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I used your SQL. The WHERE clause needed to be moved to the end.